# What does it mean for a space to be a normed vector space but not an inner product space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

So I just wanted to clarify that being a normed vector space that is not an inner product space, just means that we cannot induce an inner product using that norm on the vector space.

And that if the parallelogram identity doesn't hold, this means that we cannot find an inner product on that vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the norm is not derived from an inner product. Thus if $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the norm on your vector space $V$, then you can't find an inner product

$$\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle: V \times V \to \mathbb{K}$$

such that

$$\forall v \in V: \Vert v \Vert = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$$

Comment: Thank you.                Am I correct in saying that if the parallelogram identity doesn't hold there doesn't exist any inner products on that space. Or just that there doesn't exist any inner products induced from that specific norm.

Comment: Yes, of course. The parallelogram holds for any norm induced by an inner product, so if it doesn't hold, your norm can't be induced by an inner product.

Comment: @DylanDijk But it's of course possible that another norm (which may be equivalent to the given one) derives from an inner product. This is true for every finite dimensional real normed vector space, for example.